# AVFoundation for OS X. Is there a way to view multiple USB-cams simultaneously?

Tags: macos, avfoundation

At the first glance AVFoundation for Mac OS seems to be the same framework as seen on iOS. I was thinking that Apple advanced AVFoundation for OS X to the ability of capturing multiple cams simultaneously but I was not able to get two USB cams running simultaneously with my code.

If I run iChat using cam1 and photobooth using cam2 my mac is showing two camera streams simultaneously. This proofs that my system can handle it.

My code encapsulates all AVFoundation stuff in one class. While running two instances of this class, one instance always says that the session could not be created. If I turn off cam1, cam2 starts running on instance2. My question is: Did I wrote broken code (which would lead to this result), or is multiple cam support disabled by design?

Thanks in advance

Jack